# Object function is not a function

Tags: javascript, oop, function, object

```
var plugin = {
    Init: function() {
        this.UpdateUI();
        if (this.Status() == 1) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    },
    Status: function() {
        ...
    },
    UpdateUI: function() {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is the basic code. The problem is, when Init is called, the following errors appear:

```
this.UpdateUI is not a function
this.Status is not a function
```

Can someone tell me what's the problem with my code?

Comment: Can you post the code that calls `Init()`?

Comment: scoping issues, `this` isn't referring to plugin, it's referring to the init function. If you placed the Status and UpdateUI functions within the init function, then your code would work correctly. I think bardiir has the correct solution for you.

Comment: I think we just found one of the ugly sides of javascript and according to the votes on my answer there seem to be some differenting viewpoints about this :D

Comment: @CoryDanielson: We don't know what `this` refers to because we don't know how `Init` is being called. But it isn't a scoping issue, and merely placing the functions inside the `Init` function will not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `this` inside `plugin.Init` refers to `plugin.Init` and not to `plugin` itself. Change it like this:

```
var plugin = {
    Init: function() {
        plugin.UpdateUI();
        if (plugin.Status() == 1) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    },
    Status: function() {
        ...
    },
    UpdateUI: function() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Prototyped:

```
function Plugin(){
  var self = this;

  this.Init = function() {
    self.UpdateUI();
    if (self.Status() == 1) {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
  };
}

Plugin.prototype.status = function() {
            ...
  };
Plugin.prototype.UpdateUI: function() {
    ...
  }

var plugin = new Plugin();
```

Comment: Why would `this` not penetrate inside a function body? Are you sure this is even possible?

Comment: right, it is invalid code like that. You need to replace `self` with `plugin`

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought I saw a prototype declaration. Indeed, in an object literal you cannot do that. I modified the code to refer to `plugin` directly, although I think the better approach would be to declare an actual class/prototype.

Comment: -1, sorry. The premise is wrong, and the "fix" would break OOP (in that the methods will always refer to `plugin` even if they're copied to a different object).

Comment: Added a little example of what I mean by that.

Comment: @ruakh What is there 'OOP' about copying a method to another object? But in general, I agree, that's why I added another piece of code that I think is better.

Comment: @GolezTrol: That's how OOP works in JavaScript: a method should always operate on the object it's called on. You're obviously familiar with prototypes (which work in a slightly different way -- the method isn't actually copied -- but require the same principle); similar things can also be done by copying methods, e.g., to create mix-ins.

Comment: Also, your current code labeled "Prototype" is a total mess, with a bizarre mixture of `this`, `self`, and `plugin`.

Comment: I ended up using this, since the variable name will always remain the same.

Comment: Actually, wait a sec . . . I retract my statement that you're obviously familiar with prototypes: your example labeled "Prototyped" is actually not using prototypes at all, but rather, a constructor function.

Answer (score 2):

In the Context where init is called this might be something else.

Try to use `plugin.UpdateUI` and `plugin.Status` instead, that always references the correct functions.